# При загрузке выдаёт BusyBox v1.17.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)

Tags: linux

У меня ОС Linux 2.6/38-13, на Ubuntu, и грузится, я так понимаю, через GNU GRUB version 1.99~rc1-13ubuntu3.

При загрузке выдаёт:

> BusyBox v1.17.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)Enter`help`for a list of built-in commands(initramfs)

Набираю help, выдаёт:

> [alias break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec exit export fals getopts hash help let local printf pwd read readonly return set shift test time trap true type ulimit umask unalias unset wait[ [[ ash awk basename blockdev cat chmod chroot chvt clear cmp cp cut deallocvt df dnsdomainname du dumpkmap echo egrep env expr false fbset fdflush fgrep find grep gunzip gzip hostname ifconfig ip kill ln loadfont loadkmap ls mkdir mkfifo mknod mkswap mktemp modinfo mjre mount mv openvt pidof printf ps pwd readlink reset rm rmdir sed setkeycodes sh sleep sort stat static-sh stty sync tail tee test touch tr true tty umount uname uniq wc wget which yea zcat

Что делать с этим?

---

добавлено из комментария:

я пробую запустить старый(не известный мне) комп...пишет, что установлены Ubuntu,Linux 2.6.38-13-generic с двумя тестовыми режимами и с режимом прежних версий(8 шт.), ещё есть режим recovery mode...ни один не запускается(чёрный экран,а потом busybox)

Comment: она когда-нибудь нормально грузилась ? это похоже на недоустановленную систему больше всего. что пишет перед тем как выдать busybox ?

Comment: Незнаю,я пробую запустить старый(не известный мне) комп...пишет, что установлены Ubuntu,Linux 2.6.38-13-generic с двумя тестовыми режимами и с режимом прежних версий(8 шт.), ещё есть режим recovery mode...ни один не запускается(чёрный экран,а потом busybox)

Answer (score 1):

глобальная причина одна: возникла какая-то проблема при работе *initrd* (образ «минимальной» файловой системы).

судя по тому, что вы видите приглашение программы *busybox*, это значит, что и программа *linux* и *initrd* благополучно распаковались, программа *grub* смогла передать управление программе *linux*, а вот при выполнении `/sbin/init` из *initrd* возникла ошибка, и была загружена программа *busybox* — минималистическая оболочка, которой обычно комплектуют *initrd*.

не имея дополнительной информации (достаточно большого объёма), о конкретной причине сбоя можно лишь гадать.